# Авторизация с помощью CURL

Tags: curl, php, post, авторизация

Пытаюсь произвести авторизацию на сайте http://www.streetinsider.com/login.php 
При просмотре cookie при авторизации через браузер появляется динамическое поле `login_user_hash` 
CUrl на сервере подключен, права на файл cookie2.txt 0777.

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie2.txt"); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; ru; rv:1.9.1.3) Gecko/20090824 Firefox/3.5.3'); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.streetinsider.com/login.php'); 
$html = curl_exec($curl);

$post = "action=account&redirect=login.php%3F&radiobutton=old&loginemail=sotpokercash%40gmail.com&password=5095362sot&login%5Bremember_me%5D=remember_me&LoginChoice=Sign+In+to+Secure+Area";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.streetinsider.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$html = curl_exec($curl);
echo $html;
```

Сильно не пинайте, только учусь, код взят и переработан из найденного здесь решения

Comment: Так проблема-то в чем?

Comment: не логинится и cookie2.txt пуст

Comment: `cookie2.txt` и будет пуст, потому что Вы его не сохраняете. А авторизация проходит, проверяйте настройки сервера.

Comment: спасибо всем, все решено
curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt"):

Answer (score 0):

```
$email = 'dxcdfg@mail.ru';
$password = 'passsss';
$data = array(
    'action' => 'account',
    'redirect' => 'login.php?',
    'radiobutton' => 'old',
    'loginemail' => $email,
    'password' => $password,
    'LoginChoice' => 'Sign In to Secure Area'
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.streetinsider.com/login.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

---

дальше сам. считай заголовки получил, теперь проверяй на наличие Cookie.